# Remove cart from page bottom footer area

Tags: addtocart

I Have Showing In My Website Cart In footer Area So Please Tell Me How To I Can Remove From here...
I Have Tried To Edit Addtocart.phtml but there is i have not found any valuable response...
my Website Url Is mkzon.com u Can See Here....
[image]

Comment: set display none in css.

Answer (score 0):

for me it seems to be a css issue or the theme feature . You may want to hide it or remove it.
You  need to know the phtml from where this section is being rendered. For that you may turn on the template hints. To Turn on template hints follow these steps:

```
1) Log into the magento back-end admin
2) Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3) Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
4)Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
5) Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.
```

clear cache and refresh the page and you must see the phtml from where this section is rendered and you may do whatever you want.

Comment: I Have A Find File Same app/design/frontend/amazon/default/template/cmsmart/ajaxcart/view/sidebar/default.phtml then now please tell me how to i can remove

Comment: you have the file. so if you want to hide the content you may add display:none in style and if you want to remove this then you may comment the code. but before doing this make sure that this template is not being used any where else or just simply hide it and check if it is affecting your site.